# Олія, масло, мастило

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

[image: масло/олія ші]

Є такий косметичний препарат, як ***масло/олія ші*** (картинка [звідси](http://adverso.com.ua/oleum-shea.html)).

Англійською він називається [*Shea **butter***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shea_butter).

Згідно з Словником української мови (11 томів)

> **[Олія](http://sum.in.ua/s/olija)** *Рідка жирова речовина, яку добувають з деяких рослин (переважно з їх насіння або плодів).*
>
> **[Масло](http://sum.in.ua/s/maslo)** *1. Харчовий продукт, який виробляють збиванням вершків або сметани. 2. Жирова речовина, яку видобувають із мінеральних
>   речовин.*
>
> **[Мастило](http://sum.in.ua/s/mastylo)** *Жирова речовина для змащування поверхонь тертя механізмів і деталей машин.*

Як правильно вживати/писати: ***масло ші*** чи ***олія ші***?

Comment: Додав трошки тексту і «картинку для привернення уваги», але якщо це не те, що малося на увазі, то я приберу.

Comment: @bytebuster, з одного боку — завдяки картинці стало зрозуміло про що мова, тож дуже добре. З іншого — основна дилема: як називати тверде масло ші (маслом чи олією), а з Вашим зображенням увага відразу фокусується на рідких варіантах, а тверді випадають із поля зору. Тож не знаю, як краще.

Comment: @Sasha, саме це я і мав на увазі. І на додачу, англійська версія, яка суперечить висновкам у відповіді, тому я подумав, що її краще додати до запитання. І теж не упевнений, що правильно зробив.

Comment: @bytebuster, я б або додав поруч дві картинки (рідкої і твердої), необов'язково тверду з українським підписом (наприклад: [1](//www.amazon.com/Certified-Unrefined-Protective-Moisturizer-Body/dp/B00GMRJWPY) або [2](//www.minebotanicals.com/shea-butter-essential-oil)) — і ще рядок тексту «буває рідка й тверда» — або прибрав обидві. Адже запитання не обмежується рідким  агрегатним станом.

Answer (score 4):

Справа в тому, що ця речовина буває різної консистенції — рідкої і твердої. У різних джерелах їх називають то маслом, то олією, тому й з'являються сумніви. На сайтах опису косметичних засобів часто пишуть ***масло ши (ші, каріте)***, але я вважаю, що це не правильно. Оскільки джерело походження ("*[олія — ..жирова речовина, яку добувають з деяких рослин](http://sum.in.ua/s/olija)*"; "*[масло.. виробляють збиванням вершків або сметани](http://sum.in.ua/s/maslo)*") важливіше за консистенцію ("*[олія — рідка](http://sum.in.ua/s/olija)*").

Зокрема в статті Вікіпедії "***[Олія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F)***" зазначено, що:

> …під олією
>   розуміють лише рослинні олії та жири (у тому числі, тверді —
>   наприклад, пальмова олія), на відміну від тваринних жирових продуктів
>   (які оліями називати не прийнято; зокрема, не слід плутати олію з
>   маслом — продуктом переробки вершків чи сметани).

Оскільки дана речовина добувається з *плодів та насіння дерева ші (каріте)*, правильно було б писати та вживати ***олія дерева ші.***

Підтвердження цьому можемо побачити у статті ***[Гінзбурга та  Коваленка](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328181037/http://msu.kharkov.ua/tc/cons/olie.html#q1)***:

> Виходячи з традицій української фахової мови, вимог системності та
>   однозначної відповідності терміна поняттю, вживаймо:
>
> 1) український термін ***масло*** тільки для концентрату молочного жиру, тобто в значенні рос. животное масло, а термін ***олія*** - для жирів
>   рослинного походження незалежно від температури їх застигання, тобто в
>   значенні рос. растительное масло;
>
> 2) для назв твердих жирів рослинного походження термінологічні словосполуки зі словом ***олія***, тобто кокосова ***олія***, какаова ***олія***
>   (какао-***олія***), пальмова ***олія*** тощо.

Проте це не єдина точка зору, адже у Словнику української мови online. Томи 1-8(А-Мішурний) присутній наступний приклад для слова "***масло***": "*[Масла для шкіри обличчя широко використовують в косметології (з наук.-попул. літ.)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50001&page=1578)*".