# «Ші» чи «ши» (про дерево Vitellaria paradoxa, інакше відоме як каріте)?

Tags: запозичені-слова, орфографія

**Ші**/**ши** (від англ. shea) та **каріте́** (від фр. karité) — це назви [дерева Vitellaria paradoxa («Тропічне дерево родини Сапотові, єдиний вид роду Vitellaria. Походить з Африки. Плоди дерева використовуються в їжу, а також для виробництва олії» © Вікіпедія)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitellaria).

- Видання «Відомості Верховної Ради України» (2007) — «[ши](//books.google.com/books?id=GxQmAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B8+%D1%88%D0%B8%22)».
- Журнал «Українська культура» (2008) — «[ши](//books.google.com/books?id=Xk87AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F+%D1%88%D0%B8%22)».
- Один з виробників/імпортерів (зокрема на упаковці) — «[ші](http://adverso.com.ua/oleum-shea.html)».
- Вікіпедія (2017) — «[ші](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitellaria)».

То як все-таки правильно?

Comment: Related https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3315/

Comment: @bytebuster, я, власне, тому́ й поставив це питання, що в то́му спочатку було написано «ши».

Comment: @Follower, та я й не кажу, що написано, що duplicated. Bytebuster повідомив, що є схожий, а я повідомив, що не просто схожий, а навіть першопричина.

Comment: А чому карІте, а не карИте? Хіба тут не застосовується правило дев'ятки у словах іншомовного походження?

Comment: @ЮлияПлахотная, чесно кажучи, не знаю, як правильно: каріте чи карите. За [правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5v1), здається, мало б бути карите, але в [книжках](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac11&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=каріте) принаймні з 1958 року пишуть каріте (можливо, маючи на це якісь причини). Те, що вище, — це радше запитання, а не тверждення (я хотів з'ясувати про ши/ші, зацитувавши при цьому інші назви з [вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=30796799)).

Answer (score 6):

Хм, відразу сам і відповім.

[«Правопис» 2015, § 90.5.а.4](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5a4):

> **І** пишеться <…> після приголосних у кінці невідмінюваних слів: *візаві́*, *журі́*, *колі́брі*, *мерсі́*, *парі́*, *попурі́*, *таксі́*, *харакі́рі*…

Отже здається, на *-і*: **ші**.